# Iterate through arraylist and assign value for first and last value that fulfills requirement

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have a method that passes in an arraylist of data and a printwriter to print my output into a csv file. The name of the arraylist is records.

```
for (String record: records){
 String[] recordSplit = record.split(",");
 double value = Double.parseDouble(recordSplit[2]);

 writer.println(record);
 }
```

As it iterates through the arraylist, the codes are supposed to print onto the csv file line by line. (String record) However, what I want to do is as it loops, I want to check for value that is less than 20 `value <= 20` and the first value in the arraylist to fulfill that condition will have another column in the csv file output e.g.

```
record += ",Start Value";
```

and then the iterator reaches the LAST value that fulfills the condition it will have an extra column like so:

```
record += ",End Value";
```

[image]

I illustrated the concept in the image above. This is the arraylist, "id, name, value" there are some more attributes that are irrelevant to the question behind value so I'll leave it out. Anyways, value = 100 can be treated like a "forbidden value", so the moment when right before when the loop reaches the end of the arraylist, OR sees the value 100 again, that value will be assigned "End" value. 
can this actually be done? i'm quite an amateur at java so please be kind, thanks!

Anyways, the output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: 20 < 20? For writing the "End value", you'll have to look to the next entry, so I suggest you use a standard forloop instead of a for-each.

Comment: @aioobe Why 15? The values can be anything.

Comment: @Manu, yep. Misread the question.

Comment: Your example isn't in line with your description. The first line with value less then 20 should be the "Start Value" but you marked a line where the value is equal to 20.  If the "Start Value " should be less or equal to 20 then the "End Value" is marked wrong. As you said the next following line which fulfil the condition should be the "End Value". If the first line with 20 in your example is the "Start Value" then the "End Value" should be 12 not 15. Please have a look and amend you example to be consistent.

Comment: So you want to start looking at the values right below the first 100 (in your example the 20 on row 2), and then keep looping until you've reached a 100 again, and the last value above that 100, which is below 20, is your end (in this case the 15 on row 4)? A few questions that pop up: Is it always < 20, or is it < FirstValueBelowFirst100 (so if C2 = 40, it would be < 40 instead)? If C4 would have been 21, would the end be at the 12 (row 3) instead? And: What is the purpose of this? Perhaps a better solution can be found when we know what your goal is (instead of just this possible solution).

Comment: @SubOptimal and everyone else: SORRY my bad the images are just examples typed out by me to illustrate the point, it's not the actual data. Should be value <= 20.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen hi kevin, basically my goal is to scan through all the data, identify the first and last records that has a value of < 20. the last value may not always be 100 like shown above, the last value could be 19, and if that's the case it will be the assigned "End Value". this value is actually a distance and i want to identify the most accurate range the record has that distance.

Comment: @user3763216 Hmm, in that case I don't really understand why the 8 on row 7 isn't the end value. Or do you mean that it's either the last value `<=  20` when no more 100s occur (so could be the 19 in the very last row as you've stated in your last comment), or if a 100 does occur, it's the first value `<= 20` above that 100? So: [100, 20, 12, 15, 19] -> Begin = 20, End = 19 OR [45, 5, 100, 4, 12, 100, 6] -> Begin = 4, End = 12 OR [2, 3, 100, 4, 5, 60] -> Begin = 4, End = 5, etc.?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes, it's not the end value because a 100 occured before that! so i wanna find the range (esp the start and end points) where all the values are < 20 and have no 100 :-)

Comment: @user3763216 Could you please provide some examples in the way KevinCruijssen did to explain what different rules you want to implement.

Comment: @SubOptimal all his examples are accurate in showing what i wanna implement! so basically the min and max value of the range that doesn't have any value from 21 onwards. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simplified but working example from which you could start. The snippet uses the example values from Kevins comment.

Here a short explanation how the different states are determined

#### end value

- it's the last value to process
- or we found already the start value and the next value is bigger then the upper bound value

#### start value

- we found already the start indicator but not the start value
  and the current value is less or equal to the upper bound value

example snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] samples = {
        {100, 20, 12, 15, 19},
        {45, 5, 100, 4, 12, 100, 6},
        {2, 3, 100, 4, 5, 60}
    };
    outputValues(samples);
}

private static void outputValues(int[][] samples) {
    int startIndicator = 100;
    int upperBound = 20;
    for (int[] sample : samples) {
    int startIndicator = 100;
    int upperBound = 20;
    for (int[] sample : samples) {
        System.out.println("---------------");
        boolean startIndicatorFound = false;
        boolean startValueFound = false;
        boolean endValueFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
            int value = sample[i];
            System.out.printf("%d", value);
            if (endValueFound) {
                // do nothing
            } else if (i == (sample.length - 1)
                    || startValueFound && sample[i + 1] > upperBound) {
                endValueFound = true;
                System.out.print(",End Value");
            } else if (startIndicatorFound && !startValueFound
                    && value <= upperBound) {
                startValueFound = true;
                System.out.print(",Start Value");
            } else if (!startIndicatorFound && value == startIndicator) {
                startIndicatorFound = true;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
---------------
100
20,Start Value
12
15
19,End Value
---------------
45
5
100
4,Start Value
12,End Value
100
6
---------------
2
3
100
4,Start Value
5,End Value
60
```

There are still edge cases which might not be covered by the current example.

Comment: For the output, is the first result a typo? the end value is supposedly 19, right?

Comment: Thank you so much it is working like I need it to! CHEERS MATE have a good week you're awesome

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
Boolean started = false; // To keep track if we already wrote "Start Value"
for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    String record = records.get(i);

    String[] recordSplit = record.split(",");
    double value = Double.parseDouble(recordSplit[2]);

    if(value < 20 && ! started) { // Starting here
        writer.println(record + ",Start Value");
        started = true;
        continue; // Go to next record
    }

    if(i < records.length - 1) { // There is a next value
        if(Double.parseDouble(records.get(i + 1).split(",")[2]) < 20) {
            // Next value is also smaller than 20, so keep going
            writer.println(record);
        } else {
            writer.println(record + ",End Value");
            started = false; // So we can start again later
    } else {
        writer.println(record);
    }
}
```

(Not tested)

Comment: Is there any reason to use `Boolean` objects instead of plain `boolean` values?